# in drupal 7, views_get_view('VIEWNAME') get a error?

Tags: views

I want to embed a view in the tpl.php, so I am using the views_get_view('VIEWNAME') function.Here is what I am doing the tpl.php.

```
<?php
   $view = views_get_view('MapView');  
   print $view->preview('default');
?>
```

"MapView" is the view's name, I am not sure the argument in the views_get_view is the machine name or human readable name, in fact in my example is using the human readable name, because I can't find the machine name in the drupal view configuration

anyway, I get a error saying "Fatal error: Call to a member function preview() on a non-object", seems like I didn't fetch the view in the correct ?

any idea ?

Comment: You need a machine name of a View. It can be found in edit url (`/admin/structure/views/view/%machine_name%/edit`) or with exporting a View (`$view->name` will contain a machine_name.

Comment: @kalabro I wonder why you chose to make this a comment instead of an answer. It perfectly answers the question the user824624 asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even thought the documentation for [views_get_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7) refers to `$name` as the name of the view, what the function wants is the machine name of the view.

You should always check the value returned from the function is not `NULL`, as the function doesn't return any value, if it doesn't find the view with that name.

```
  ctools_include('export');
  $view = ctools_export_crud_load('views_view', $name);
  if ($view) {
    $view->update();
    return $view->clone_view();
  }
```

[views_embed_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7), for example, uses the following code.

```
  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }

  return $view->preview($display_id, $args);
```

You should use similar code, avoiding to call `$view->access()` if the view should always be visible, independently from the permission the currently logged-in user has. If you need to show the view only when the user has the permission to see it, then you should consider using `views_embed_view()`.